# Getting Mutating Tables (ORA-04091) when just doing a select on old = new

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having trouble doing a simple select count on a trigger in oracle. I keep getting an ORA-04091:

```
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  legal_amount INT;
BEGIN

SELECT count(*)
INTO legal_amount 
FROM table 
WHERE :old.TBL_ID = :new.TBL_ID; /* Many more AND clauses here */

IF (legal_amount = 0) THEN
  no_legal_amount_procedure(:new.TBL_ID);
END IF;

ELSE
  legal_amount_procedure(:new.TBL_ID);
END IF;

END;
```

It is the select statement that is causing the ORA-04091 error.

The way we fixed this before was by doing a PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION but I need to get rid of that because it is causing other problems (selecting in an autonomous transaction vs uncommited data needed from old transaction = null results).

I have also tried to follow the asktom tutorial found [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936) but without success because of the amount of AND clauses and the fact that this is a FOR EACH ROW statement. I hope that this will be a last resort.

I am aware that doing business logic in triggers is bad. But without access to the source code this is the only way to solve it.

Comment: What are the procedures `no_legal_amount_procedure` and `legal_amount_procedure` used for? Does the `SELECT count(*)..` also touch the row which was modified? You use `:old` and `:new` in the `AFTER INSERT` trigger. Shouldn't there be some condition like `IF UPDATING THEN ... IF INSERTING THEN ...'.

Comment: This is just a simplified example and may not be 100% correct syntax. Yes there is a IF UPDATING THEN statement. The two legal_amount procedures is actually a procedure on two different standards on how to convert a document.

Comment: It it possible that these procedures can modify it's arguments? Are they defined as `IN` `IN OUT` or `IN OUT NOCOPY`?.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense: `WHERE :old.TBL_ID = :new.TBL_ID` as it essentially means "if I haven't updated the TBL_ID".  Did you mean `WHERE TBL_ID = :new.TBL_ID`?

Comment: Following the Tom Kyte method is the way to go if you must do this with triggers.  What is it about the AND clauses (that you don't show) that makes this difficult?  It is simply a matter of "remembering" any values you are going to need later in the package array(s).

Comment: If you must query the same table in the trigger then try compound trigger. But it is not good idea to query the same table...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a trigger, wrap the whole insert with a stored procedure. This is an example for INSERT only:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_table (in_tbl_id INTEGER, ...[other attrs])
IS
  v_legal_amount INTEGER;

BEGIN
  SELECT count(*)
  INTO v_legal_amount 
  FROM table 
  WHERE tbl_id = in_tbl_id
  /* Many more AND clauses here */;

  INSERT INTO table VALUES (tbl_id, ...);

  IF (v_legal_amount = 0) THEN
    no_legal_amount_procedure (in_tbl_id);
  ELSE
    legal_amount_procedure (in_tbl_id);
  END IF;

END;
```